# NSBatchDeleteResult - no arguments accepted

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to clear all entity values in stored using core data. Having looked at other examples of doing this, my code so far is:

```swift
let fScheme = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Scheme")

let rScheme = NSBatchDeleteResult(fetchRequest: fScheme)
```

at this point i'm getting an error **"Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"**

I've tried a number of things, but not found a solution to this.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Add output and if you are getting any errors will help to understand your problem better, also a little context might help people to offer another solution

Comment: Please edit your answer to show your actual code. There's no such class as `NSBacthDeleteResult`, and I don't know if that's just a typo or if you meant a different class.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `NSBatchDeleteRequest` not <strike>`NSBatchDeleteResult`</strike>.